# Adding text to image, trying to change the color of text

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

I am adding text to image using the code mentioned below. But the problem am facing is that the color and font size not changing. I am trying to change the font size, not happening and don't know how to change color.

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text
{
// set the font type and size
//UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:txtView.font];
//CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0f]]; // label or textview
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]
                             };
CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{
                                         NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]
                                         }];

// check if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (iOS is 4.0+)
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);
else
    // iOS is < 4.0
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

//[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.0f]];
CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width,size.height);

NSStringDrawingContext *drawingContext = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
drawingContext.minimumScaleFactor = 1.5;

[text drawWithRect:drawRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attributes context:drawingContext];
UIImage *testImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return testImg;
}
```

Please guide, why font size not changing, what is wrong in the code nad how to change color of this text also.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got myself.

```
[theText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)
              withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor] }];
```